Modeling non-negative time series with square root decay?
Q: How should I model a non-negative time series $y_t$ which exhibits square-root decay? More specifically, a time series $y_t$ whose square-root differences $\sqrt{y_t}-\sqrt{y_{t-1}}$ are linear and negative in expectation. More specifically, a time series $y_t$ such that its square root transform $\sqrt{y_t} \sim \mathrm{ARIMA}(p,1,q)$, approximately.
I thought a square-root transform of the data (appx., Box-Cox transform with $\lambda=0.5$) prior to ARIMA modeling would be suitable.
But then I observed forecasts of my original series curling upward later in the forecast period. After investigating, it made sense to me why. Technically, we can't ever say that a time series $\sqrt{y_t}\sim\mathrm{ARIMA}(p,d,q)$ since the square-root transform is only onto the positive number line while the white noise is onto the entire real number line. This isn't a problem for the log-transform, which is onto the entire real number line.
Good to know. But then, what does the practitioner typically do here?

ARIMA model $\log(y_t)$, even though the log-transform over-stabilizes $y_t$, so to speak?
ARIMA model the untransformed non-negative data $y_t$ and
truncate any forecasts which go below zero?
Use one of the many alternative transformations implemented in the trafo R package, e.g., square root shift, Bickel-Docksum, Yeo-Johnson.
exit the world of simple, off-the-shelf solutions and do some kind of GLM for Poisson, negative binomial, gamma, etc. link?

I can't believe I've never run into this issue before. I guess I'm used to modeling data which is growing, not decaying. Still, I would have expected a comment on it somewhere, at some point!
See below for simulation code demonstrating my point.
library(forecast)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(fabletools)
library(feasts)

# simulate non-negative square-root decay data
set.seed(10)
mu=-3
x0=100
N=24
x<-cumsum(c(x0,mu+rnorm(N))) # this would be the transformed series
plot(x,type='l')


y<-x^2 # this would be the target, observed series
feasts::guerrero(y) # 0.4675001 ~ 0.5, as expected

# fit 
fit<-auto.arima(x)
summary(fit)
fit$coef # drift: -3.523052 ~ 3, as expected
fcs<-forecast(fit,h=12)
plot(fcs) # forecast will curl up later in series


plot(fcs$mean^2) # yes, forecast curls up later in series


# try using the `lambda` parameter directly
fit2<-auto.arima(x,lambda=0.5)
fcs2<-forecast(fit2,h=2)
plot(fcs2) 
# won't forecast beyond 2 periods, I'm stumped, moving on.


dat <- tsibble(idx=1:(N+1),y=y,index='idx')
dat %>%
  model(s_arima=ARIMA(sqrt(y))) %>%
  forecast(h=12) %>%
  autoplot() # same curl upward, even in the fable package


dat %>%
  model(s_arima=ARIMA(box_cox(y,lambda=0.5))) %>%
  forecast(h=12) %>%
  autoplot() 
# surprisingly, forecasted y actually goes negative here
# I guess `ARIMA` doesn't recognize `box_cox` as transform for which it can
# back transform?


